# How to grep for non-whitespaces adjacent to slashes

Tags: regex, grep, whitespace, slash

I want to grep for comments without a space after them...

The following grep expression **does not work** to extract **//abc** patterns, but I'm not sure why...

`echo "//asdf" | grep '//^[ ]*'` Should return `//asdf`, whereas

`echo "// asdf" | grep '//^[ ]*'` should return nothing at all.

To conclude, the above grep statement is broken somehow, but it appears that the expression above is saying "two slashes adjacent to a non- whitespace".

- What is the proper way to grep for "two slashes adjacent to a whitespace"?
- Concretely, how should i modify `'//^[ ]*'` to match the following expressions: `//a`, `//asdfasdf`, `//1234`, `//another one 1234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the negation `^` has to be placed **inside** the `[ ]` block:

```
$ echo "//asdf" | grep '//[^ ]'
//asdf
$ echo "// asdf" | grep '//[^ ]'
```

That is, use `[^ ]` instead of `^[ ]`. This way, [saying `[^ ]`](https://regex101.com/r/xP8vZ1/1) you match a single character not present in the list.

Whereas [when you were saying `^\[ \]`](https://regex101.com/r/rK1hJ8/1) you were saying:

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `[ ]` match a single character present in the list below

Answer (score 1):

Two slashes followed by a space

```
grep '//[ ]'
```

Two slashes followed by a non-space character

```
grep '//[^ ]'
```